# RDP printer redirection doesn't work from Windows computer, but works from Mac

Tags: printing, rdp, windows-server-2019

I have 1 Mac and 1 Windows.

- From the Mac, using Microsoft RDP, I connect to a Windows Server 2019 and I can see my local printer (redirected) in the Windows server. I can print without any problem.
- From the Windows, using RDP, I connect do the same Windows server and I don't see my local printer.

Notes:

1. I configured both RDP to enable local resources (printer)
2. I didn't install the printer driver in the server. Since I can use it from the Mac, I conclude that I don't need to install it in the server.

Any idea why I can't see the local printer from the Windows computer and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue and at a loss as for how to fix it.

Comment: Hi. Yes, if I can remember it correctly, I had to install the printer driver in the remote server.

Comment: Thanks so much! That didn't initially seem like the issue, but you're right. One thing to note for anyone else experiencing this is that it was important that I installed the printer driver both locally and on the server, and that even though both my local computer and the server were using the Microsoft IPP driver initially, that didn't work. I had to install the manufacturer driver for the printer.